# Solving the system $a^x=4x+1$, $a^y=7y+6$, $x+y=5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

How can I solve this exponential equation?

> $$ a>1 $$
> $$ a^x=4x+1 $$
> $$ a^y=7y+6 $$
> $$ x+y=5 $$
> $a,x,y$ are real numbers

One answer is $$ a=3, x=2, y=3$$

How can I solve this?

Help me please.

Comment: There are some obvious first steps you can take. Substitute $x=y-5$, for example. Please show some effort.

Comment: Welcome to MSE community @nm00062 What is your attempt? What did you try??

Comment: i did some simple transfromation of equation, but i couldnt get any closer to answer. i used lambert w function but i can only get approximate number of x and y not real number

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could give me directions on this problem.

Comment: To @AlvinL: perhaps it is typo, i.e. $x=5-y$.

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak correct, ty.

Answer (score 3):

As such, the first two equations would require the use the Lambert W function in order to tackle the combination of the exponentials with the linear terms. However, in the present case, we are able to get rid of the exponential with the help of the following trick. Indeed, one has $a^{x+y} = (4x+1)(7y+6)$ by multiplying the two equations and $a^5 = (4x+1)(7(5-x)+6)$ since $x+y = 5$.

Now, we face a mere quadratic equation, namely $28x^2 - 157x + a^5 - 41 = 0$, hence the two solutions $x_\pm = \frac{157 \pm \sqrt{29241 - 112a^5}}{56}$. Of course, those solutions are real only when $112a^5 \le 29241$. Finally, one has $y_\pm = 5 - x_\pm$. You can check that $a = 3$ leads to $x_+ = 2$ and $y_+ = 3$, as well as $x_- = \frac{101}{28}$ and $y_- = \frac{39}{28}$.

Comment: i tried this way(but i get nothing...). i think case of a=3, x=2, y=3 is the only answer. if a=3 and x=101/28, then 3^(101/28)=4(101/28)+1 is right. Thank you so much for your answer. i really appreciate it

Comment: it seems any a which is less than 3.04337(112a^5 <=29241) can answer but if we get correspond x, y, they dont meet equations.

Comment: I might have made a slight computation error somewhere, for instance when copying an intermediate result; nevertheless, you see the procedure to apply.